# I am getting error while installing Herocu with snap

Tags: heroku

Here is problem. I installed heroku before But i did not recognized herocu commands like heroku login
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code. (And _especially_ don't use a screenshot of your whole desktop.)

Comment: This isn't really a Heroku question and it _definitely_ doesn't have anything to do with Django. It's a question about installing software via `snap` and is likely a better fit on [su] or [unix.se] or [ubuntu.se].